# How to convert wav file to mp4 using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, mp4

I am having a wav file.How to convert wav file into mp4 file container format with AAC as audio stream  using FFmpeg in android.I know how compile and port ffmpeg for android.Can anybody give me right direction

thanks,

Comment: You are searching for the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to compile [libfaac](http://www.audiocoding.com/downloads.html) if you want to have a decent quality encoder. Then, something like `ffmpeg -i foo.wav -vn -acodec libfaac -ab BITRATE output.mp4` should do the trick.

Comment: After downloading the zip file and extracting it, what steps should I use to compile that libfaac source code, and reference it using your command?  What tools (ie: IDE) do I need for compilation?