# is there a way to record audio in mp4 using ruby on rails / web / html5

Tags: html, audio, mp4, recorder

I would like to find a way to record audio (not video) in mp4 format on the web.

Reason for this is ios/android are both generating in this format, and I want to be able to be consistent with the audio format. (android mediarecorder for example does not do mp3, thats the reason why this is the preferred format)

Is there a recorder that records mp4 audio for web/html5/rails?

UPDATE:

I found out recorderjs
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Im guessing if I could change encodeWAV to encodeMPEG4 in here:
https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js

This is the target audio outcome Im trying to achieve:

Type: Audio

Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)

Comment: I would look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16498273/1380867

Comment: cant find mp4. could it be using html5 video api but just set to mic only. not quite sure.

Comment: How about converting the WAV to MP4 after capture via libfaac? (See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943403/365218)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example which uses [Web Audio API](http://html5-examples.craic.com/microphone_input_with_spectrogram.html). I think your front-end(HTML and Javascript) should handle audio recording which will generate mp4 file then you can save it in your rails app via Carrierwave or something else.

Comment: hmm, im not sure if it does generate mp4. so far i'ved found other formats. https://github.com/higuma/web-audio-recorder-js. not clear yet how to build the file codec (aac) and container for mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ffmpeg,

www.ffmpeg.org

[streamio-ffmpeg](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg)