# ffmpeg : how to take wav as audio input for creating a video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, wav

I'm trying to use ffmpeg for rendering video where an audio file and image are taken as inputs, and turned into a video with the same dimensions as the image with the audio file playing for the duration of the video (basically a music video).

I have this working for flac and mp3 files, my ffmpeg command for mp3 is below:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "front.png" -i "testMP3file.mp3" -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict -2 "testMP3fileOutput1.mp4"
```

How can I take wav audio files as input instead of mp3? Is there a different codec I need to specify? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942631/how-to-convert-wav-file-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg-in-android/9943403) talks about download  libfaac and using that, **is there any way to take wav audio file as input using just ffmpeg without downloading a separate library?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a WAV file as input and change `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac` (or omit `-c:a` if you want to use the default encoder which is `-c:a aac` for MP4 output):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "front.png" -i "testMP3file.wav" -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a aac -shortest "testMP3fileOutput1.mp4"
```

Other changes:

- No need for `-strict -2`: it does nothing. You can remove that from your command too.
- I replaced `-pix_fmt yuv420p` with `format=yuv420p` so all your filtering is contained in the filtergraph.